# Spring MVC send and receive the parameters using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm sending the request ajax to spring controller. But it not showing anything WHen I send the request.

My ajax request

```
  $(".secs li a").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).data("value");
          $.ajax({
              url:"../tmax",
              type:"POST",
              data:{id:id},
              success: function(response){
                  $("#testdata").html(response);
              }
          })

      })
```

And my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tmax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView tmax(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("tmax");
    model.addObject("dataCOLL", userService.finddataCOLLById(id));
    return model;
}
```

I'm sending the request in the **home.jsp**. The data should get `tmax.jsp` and show in **home.jsp**.

My tmax.jsp page

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Thanx

Comment: You aren't sending parameters. You are sending a request body.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes... But the hello world should print know OR I need to get the console.log message

Comment: No it shouldn't. As there is no parameter, the request will result in an error.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok I will check

Comment: @M.Deinum Now I passed the parameter and i'm getting 404 Error

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are sending parameters (unless you didn't update your question).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am confused by your comment,he has set `data` in `ajax`,why do you say he do not sending parameter?

Comment: Because he is sending a JSON request body... A request body is not a parameter.

Comment: @Ashu : try this approach to pass parameter  data: { 
        'field1': 'hello', 
        'field2': 'hello1'
      },

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`? well,I think the user can remove this config due to he do not set dataType in ajax

Comment: Removing that might make it work, but AFAIK `.ajax` by default sends a request body with JSON and not a form request (but that could be because I'm too much into sending JSON and not forms anymore).

Comment: @M.Deinum The mistake made in the typing process, For success, I wrote sucess.

Comment: @AshokCharu Can you please share the HTML code to call this Ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using $.ajax or $.post

**Using $.ajax :**

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'tmax',   //*why you are using double dot?  url:"../tmax",* 
      data: { 
        'field1': 'hello', 
        'field2': 'hello1'
      },
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response.status);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("error");
      }
   });
```

**Using $.post :**

```
    $.post('tmax',
      { 
        'field1': 'hello', 
        'field2': 'hello1'
      },
      function (response, status) {
        alert(response.status);
      }
    );
```

The mistake made in the typing process **success** and now it's working

```
  $(".secs li a").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).data("value");
          $.ajax({
              url:"../tmax",
              type:"POST",
              data:{id:id},
              sucess: function(response){
                  $("#testdata").html(response);
              }
          })

      })
```

Comment: Your answer is not working, The problem is, i'm not getting any response

Comment: When I give URL just tmax, How you have given, I'm getting an error.  if I give ../tmax , i'm not getting anything

Comment: The problem is, I'm not getting any Error messages.

Comment: @AshokCharu Please check your ajax call working or not..  **$(".secs li a").on("click",function(e){ ** confirm it this line working or not try to alert your id